# Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined

Tags: javascript

Any idea why I have the error **Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined** ?

```
function hello() {
    console.log('hello ()');
    setTimeout("hello ()", 1000);
}
setTimeout("hello()", 1000);​
```

Here is a jsfiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/s9vLk/**

Comment: Post your code on this site instead of on a different site. Links should be supplemental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing strings to `setTimeout()` which means code in the string will effectively be `eval`ed and thus isn't running in the scope you think it's running in and so the `hello()` function isn't found.

If you change the jsfiddle options on the left from "onload" to "no wrap" it works as is because then the function will be global rather than nested inside the onload handler, but a better option is to pass a function reference to `setTimeout()`:

```
function hello() {
    console.log('hello ()');
    setTimeout(hello, 1000);
}
setTimeout(hello, 1000);
```

(Note: no parentheses after `hello`.)

Comment: best detailed answer about the string being eval'd and scope:-)

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript code in your demo runs within the `'load'` event handler (the option "onLoad" is selected). Therefore, the function `hello` is not a global function. You have to set the option to "no wrap (body)" or "no wrap (head)". That way, your JavaScript code will be global code.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/s9vLk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `hello` and the `()`.

You really should't pass the arguments as a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: I have: function hello() { ... }
this isn't a function?

Comment: Not the problem, as it never even gets that far.

Comment: That space does not produce the error. Spaces may appear between tokens, the code remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't (and shouldn't) need to reference your function name as a string.

```
function hello() {
    console.log('hello');
    setTimeout(hello, 1000);
}
setTimeout(hello, 1000);
```

Or better yet

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('hello');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I've seen a lot of examples using a string with the function name as argument setTimeout('MyFunction()', 1000);
Why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: @Matthew why it doesn't work is explained in Daniel's answer, however I was stating an alternative approach.

Comment: @Matthew - passing a string affects the scope where the code runs. See the answers that Šime and I posted.

Comment: @Matthew Passing strings to `setTimeout` should be avoided for the same reason [`eval()` should be avoided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!).